# Google Firebase Web App - Error involving Cloud Functions and Firestore

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

Recently, I tried to follow a few demos online to get started on a Google Firebase Cloud Functions Node.js server-side code for an application. Upon attempting to add a Firebase App (and Firestore with it),

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const firebase = require('firebase-admin');
require('firebase/firestore');

var serviceAccount = require("<private key>.json");

const initAppFirebase = firebase.initializeApp({
    credential: firebase.credential.cert(serviceAccount),
    databaseURL: "<URL>"
});

var db = firebase.firestore();
```

I begin to get this one error that mentions a missing "annotations.proto" file from the google-gax module (which is apparently imported at some point in Firestore).

```
Error during trigger parsing:  Error occurred while parsing your function 
triggers.
Error: The include `google\api\annotations.proto` was not found.
    at Function.GoogleProtoFilesRoot._findIncludePath 
(C:\...\functions\node_modules\google-gax\lib\grpc.js:312:11)
    at GoogleProtoFilesRoot.resolvePath 
(C:\...\functions\node_modules\google-gax\lib\grpc.js:298:31)
...
    at v1beta1 (C:\...\functions\node_modules\@google- 
cloud\firestore\src\v1beta1\index.js:30:10)
    at new Firestore (C:\...\functions\node_modules\@google- 
cloud\firestore\src\index.js:229:18)
```

I have looked around on the internet, but nobody else seems to have this problem. I just reinstalled the files, but I am still getting this issue. Removing the Firestore and Firebase `initializeApp` code allows it to work, so I believe it has something to do with that.

Here are my module versions from `package.json`

```
"firebase-admin": "^5.12.0",
"firebase-functions": "^1.0.1",
"firestore": "^1.1.6",
```

Is there a way to fix this problem (botched installation, outdated libraries, missing code/requires etc.)? Thank you very much.

**EDIT**: Added code and package.json for version info. I dug around in the actual file  `\node_modules\google-gax\lib\grpc.js` and found that it tries to return a valid path leading to the import file `annotation.proto` by trying to test `google\api\annotations.proto` at each parent directory.

```
var current = originPath;
var found = fs.existsSync(path.join(current, includePath));
while (!found && current.length > 0) {
  current = current.substring(0, current.lastIndexOf(path.sep));
  found = fs.existsSync(path.join(current, includePath));
}
if (!found) {
  throw new Error('The include `' + includePath + '` was not found.');
}
return path.join(current, includePath);
```

There is, unfortunately, no such directory, though perhaps it is looking for the annotations file in `google-proto-files\google\api\annotations.proto` (but adding that file in manually leads to further errors). There is also a github issue here https://github.com/googleapis/nodejs-firestore/issues/175 mentioning it.

Comment: Could you edit your question to show the entire, minimal code that exhibits the problem (not just a couple lines)?

Comment: Sorry for not being clear! I'll add in my code as soon as I can access it.

Comment: The important thing is that you're not showing the definition of `firebase`.

Answer (score 5):

You say that you're trying to build a web app. But the code you are using is for initializing the Firebase Admin SDK in a (server-side) Node.js script.

If you want to use Firestore in your web app, start with the code you see when you click the <kbd>WEB</kbd> tab on [this page](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/quickstart):

> ```
> <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/4.12.0/firebase.js"></script>
> <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/4.12.0/firebase-firestore.js"></script>
> ```

And then:

> ```
> firebase.initializeApp({
>   apiKey: '### FIREBASE API KEY ###',
>   authDomain: '### FIREBASE AUTH DOMAIN ###',
>   projectId: '### CLOUD FIRESTORE PROJECT ID ###'
> });
>
> // Initialize Cloud Firestore through Firebase
> var db = firebase.firestore();
> ```

You can get the values in that `initializeApp` call by:

1. Going to the [<kbd>Project overview</kbd> page](https://console.firebase.google.com/u/0/project/_/overview)
2. Click <kbd>ADD ANOTHER APP</kbd>
3. Click <kbd>Add Firebase to your web app</kbd>

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer. I believe I made a mistake in my question, since I forgot to say that the code was in fact supposed to be server-side Node.js code (`index.js` in the functions folder). However, your answer did show me that I have a bit of code mismatch (I think I copied the code for database initialization under the "Web" tab rather than the "Node.js" tab). I'll try to edit the code to fix that, and I might update the question to see if it fixes the problem. Thanks again.